# Check any string except space - MVC routing

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

With this code, we are forcing to check only numbers:

```
routes.MapRoute("ById", "{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "ViewById"}, new{id = @"\d+"});
```

I see many answer about having string without space, but none of them works on MVC routing.

looking for a regex, gives me true on case of this:

> "д_test.8_.は_any_language_without.Space"

and give me false on case of:

> "a b"

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you looking for a route matching any string without space? If so you can try `^[a-zA-Z]+$` (only english alphabets)

Comment: if numbers and underscore is allowed are also allowed in string then you can try `^\w+$`

Comment: @RajeshG sorry, question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "aaaaa",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "pages", action = "view" },
    constraints: new { id = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\w]*$" } //*********this should work**
);
```